# Google App Engine modules no datastore access

Tags: google-app-engine, module, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue, gae-module

I have a project consisting of three modules, where the default and one of the background task modules are operating as expected.

My third module have the following weird behaviours:

- No access to the shared data store or memcache.
- When a task is scheduled in the default queue and should be picked up by the third module, a 404 is returned. When the same task is called manually via a browser it works fine.

It appears to be a lack of access to the shared services, but they are working so I'm pretty confused.. Have anyone come across a similar problem before?

Comment: Problem was a combination of me being silly (was not reading in query parameters correctly) and a slight lack of documentation on Google's part - Task Queue tasks does not honor dispatch.xml meaning that you'll need to set up a separate queue for each module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was a combination of me being silly (was not reading in query parameters correctly) and a slight lack of documentation on Google's part - Task Queue tasks does not honor dispatch.xml meaning that you'll need to set up a separate queue for each module

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this before, but here are a few ideas: you can try changing the module's version number and uploading it again, also dont forget to make it default. I have also run into problems with one of my modules consistently crashing due to low memory, you can try to change it to a beefier machine.